# Use standard MVC querystring to pass parameters to an action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to pass a parameter to an action from a view. But now, the format that is using the application is something like example.com/controller/action?parameter=1.

I want to use a format like this: example.com/controller/action/?parameter=1

The RouteConfig.cs that I'm using is like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

And the action link I'm using to pass the parameter is something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", "Controler", new { parameter = "1" }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg" })
```

What do I have to do to use the format I mentioned before?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Just curious, but why would using `/?parameter=1`, compared to `?parameter=1` make a difference for you?

Comment: you could add a new route: `{controller}/{action}/parameter/{id}"` which would look like `controller/action/parameter/1`

Comment: I read that this format is the standard mvc format to pass parameters between views and actions.

Comment: It is, but it is also the default route - if you want to customize a part of it you can't and will have to add another one above the default route.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your routes as follows

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/p/{id}",
        defaults: new { p=string.Empty, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: Might not be worth editing the default route which could cause issues with other areas of the app, but add it as an additional route.

Comment: Yes of course @Ric but if you look well at this new route, it corresponds to the default one and everything will work perfectly

Comment: I added a new route but nothing happens:
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Parameter",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/ctg/{id}",
                defaults: new { ctg = string.Empty, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );